# Switch characters progressively to another in a string

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, replace

How can I replace all caracteres by another with all possibilities ?

The function switch progressively all the characters by another.

```
const globalReplace = (chain) => {
    let d = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i <= chain.length - 1; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j <= d; j++) {
            console.log(chain.slice(0, chain.length - 1 - i), 'X', chain.slice(chain.length - i, chain.length + 1));
        }
        d++;
    }
    return;
};

globalReplace('ABCDE');
```

**the result is :**

ABCDX
ABCXE
ABCXE
ABXDE
ABXDE
ABXDE
AXCDE
AXCDE
AXCDE
AXCDE
XBCDE
XBCDE
XBCDE
XBCDE
XBCDE

**but i would like :**

ABCDX
ABCXE
ABCXX
ABXDE
ABXXE
ABXXX
AXCDE
AXXDE
AXXXE
AXXXX
XBCDE
XXCDE
XXXDE
XXXXE
XXXXX

Have you any ideas ? I think my function is close to the result.

Comment: Where does `X` come from in your examples? Your question is unclear.

Comment: In the console.log; it's a simple letter. This can be changed by another letter.

Comment: Is the order of output important? If not, it seems really simple. I can provide you with a python or pseudocode, I'm not versed in js.

Comment: Good question, the order isn't important. At first I thought it was simple but... no.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, order of output strings is not important. Keeping that in mind, I've written a code in python (I'm not well versed with js). You can translate it as you need.

```
def global_replace(chain, r_chr): # chain is the string to replace, r_chr is character (in your example, 'X')
    replaced_strings = []
    for i in range(0, len(chain)):
        r_str = r_chr * (i+1)          # this creates a replace str of length (i+1) with repeated r_chr
        for j in range(0, len(chain)-i):
            s = chain[:j] + r_str      # slice and replace portion of "chain" with r_str
            if j+i+1 < len(chain):     # string index error check
                s += chain[j+i+1:]
            replaced_strings.append(s)
    return replaced_strings
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample output with OP's input data?

Comment: Nevermind, I've missunderstood OP's requirements, your code works fine it seems. Can't fix that -1 =\

Comment: @Tipihack Thanks, don't worry about it. Maybe someone misunderstood my solution :)
If you find this answer helpful, consider accepting it

Comment: You're welcome :) I must test it first.